# How can I make the Hudson dashboard easier to see

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, hudson, visualization

We have a build server which is serving up Hudson results already.

These results are being displayed on a standalone screen in our development corner - it looks something like this: [image: Our Current Setup]

I would like to make these results easier to read... or rather, make failures harder to miss. Something like this: [image: Buildey]

I'm wondering if anyone has any good ideas on how to better visualise hudson test results. I could whip up some html/js to wrap around it but would prefer to find an off the shelf solution. Big red/green buttons which fill the screen are pretty much what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eXtreme feedback panel plugin in @sdmythos_gr answer is actually inspired by the basic radiator plugin for hudson which does exactly what I want.

[Radiator View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin)

[image: This is what I'm talking about]

Comment: This plugin looks interesting! I'll also give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the following plug in:

[**eXtreme Feedback Panel**](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/eXtreme+Feedback+Panel+Plugin)

You can create an extra View on the dashboard of Hudson that is not too far away from what you have in your picture... You can select the builds to add to the View and the will have a big Blue or Red Background making it easy to spot when everything turns Red!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i've just tried it and it's a little clunky when you've got a number of jobs with long strings. The multi-column view actually shows up with big gaps.

Answer (score 1):

[Buildron](http://skahal.com/buildron) is a good builds radiator option. It supports Hudson, Jenkins and TeamCity.

You can see the state of your builds in a 3D environment.

[image]